# Is the sentence "Long is the night" acceptable grammatically?

Tags: grammar

Can an adjective instead of the real subject be used before "be" as in the sentence cited above? Is this inversion acceptable for emphasis?

Comment: Closest rule I can find requires "So (+ adjective)...that..." Example: *So delicious was the food that we ate every last bite.* https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html

Answer (score 2):

This is acceptable, but quite old-fashioned; nobody would talk this way in ordinary parlance unless they were deliberately trying to come across as poetic or dramatic (there may be a subtle sense of mocking something when speaking this way). If this style were used in writing, it would generally be in a creative work, or for dramatic effect in some other type of publication.

Comment: Famous examples include *Uneasy lies the head that wears a crown* Shakespeare: *Henry IV* ("uneasy lies the head" = "sleeps badly") and *Wide is the gate, and broad is the way [to destruction]* King James Bible, Matthew 7:13. ("wide gate and broad way" = "very easy route to enter and travel")